# How do I query Last Week From Thursday to Wednesday?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get a query to pull records from last week from thursday morning at 12:00AM to Wednesday night at 12:00pm.

This needs to always run and be current. I have another query for the current week from thursday to wednesday and it actually works. I just need another query that shows results after the week has passed from last week.

I believe this query is for last week but not starting on Thursday and ending on Wednesday.

```
 SELECT collector, SUM('amountcollected') as 'totalsum' FROM commissioninfo 
   WHERE thedate >= Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())+6 day 
   AND thedate < Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())-1 day  
   GROUP BY collector ORDER BY totalsum DESC
```

Comment: Do you mean Wednesday night at midnight?  12pm is noon...do you mean noon or 11:59pm on Wednesday night?

Also, what format are dates stored in within your SQL database?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this using MySQL's own date functions, but I think I would probably just do it like this.  I'm assuming that you meant Wednesday night at 11:59:59pm though, not noon:

`$lastThursday = new DateTime("Thursday last week");`

`$wednesday = new DateTime("Wednesday");`

`$today = new DateTime("now");`

`$day = $today->format("l");`

```
if ($day == "Sunday" || $day == "Monday" || $day == "Tuesday" || $day == "Wednesday") {
    $lastThursday->modify("-1 week");
    $wednesday->modify("-1 week");
}
```

`$query = "SELECT collector, SUM('amountcollected') as 'totalsum' FROM commissioninfo WHERE thedate BETWEEN ".$lastThursday->format("Y-m-d")." AND ".$wednesday->format("Y-m-d ")." GROUP BY collector ORDER BY totalsum DESC";`

Comment: Yea that is correct, 12AM Wed Night. My date is formatted like this: 2014-12-31. Do I use exactly what you have here? Will that work the way you have it?

Comment: Edited, try it out now

Comment: I think it is pulling from the current week. Last thursday to present, would be this weeks earnings. How would I get the week before last thursday from thursday to wednesday? I appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Ah, you are probably right now that we went passed Sunday...it worked right on Saturday when I posted it, but that was because we were still in the same week as the Wednesday you were trying to get.  So basically if today is a Sunday - Wednesday we need to adjust the date, I think, by moving start and finish back by a week.  I made an edit to account for that.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work right. Yes I was trying to get it to go from Wednesday Midnight/Thursday Morning to Wednesday Midnight/Thursday Morning. I'm not sure why this isn't working for me.

Comment: I just added an update and added it below what you had. I tested this and works perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I see how you did this now. However, after this IF statement, I had to put an else statement and had to modify wednesday by 1 week. Then it worked correctly. This makes sense now since the first day of the week is Sunday, The php code gets confused and thinks it starts a new week when that isn't suppose to happen until Thursday 0:00:0:00:00. But thank you for helping me. I think I finally have it working!

Comment: What did you modify Wednesday to?  As written, my Wednesday should give you Wednesday of the current week.

Comment: Today is Sunday and it is not working. I think the modify -1 week is not working. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Or maybe the If statement Sun through Wed is not working correctly.