# The First Wednesday and Last Thursday of EVERY month in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking to pull the first Wednesday of EVERY month starting for the first day of the month.

```
SELECT
 CASE
 WHEN latestRefreshTime => ***first wednesday of every month*** THEN 'Up to Date'
 WHEN latestRefreshTime2 => ***last thursday of every month*** THEN 'Up to Date'
ELSE ' Not Up To Date'
END AS upToDate
```

I have tried using DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH) to get the first day of the month, but I am having a hard time drilling it to down to the first wednesday and for it to be dynamic so it changes every month. The same thing for the last Thursday

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I query Last Week From Thursday to Wednesday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762706/how-do-i-query-last-week-from-thursday-to-wednesday)

Answer (score 1):

Hope below BigQuery example will help you

```
WITH days AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-05-22' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-04-22' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-03-22' 
)
SELECT dt, 
  IF(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM x) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(dt)), x, x - 7) as last_thursday,
  IF(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM y) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(dt)), y, y + 7) as first_wednesday
FROM(
  SELECT dt, 
    LAST_DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE(dt), MONTH), WEEK(FRIDAY)) x,
    LAST_DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(dt, MONTH) - 1, MONTH), WEEK(THURSDAY)) y
  FROM days
)
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intermediate table with the first Wednesday and last Thursday of the month of the respective date and then aplly the rule.

```
DECLARE arbitrary_date DATE DEFAULT'2023-06-21';

WITH
-- Table with first and last day of the month for each date
first_last_day_table AS (
  SELECT
    arbitrary_date,
    DATE_TRUNC(arbitrary_date, MONTH) AS first_day_month,
    DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(arbitrary_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS last_day_month,
)

-- Table with first wednesday and last thursday for each date
SELECT
  arbitrary_date,
  first_day_month + MOD(11 - EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM first_day_month), 7) AS first_wednesday,
  last_day_month - MOD(2 + EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM last_day_month), 7) AS last_thursday
FROM first_last_day_table
```